# Is there a way to get a list of all closeby users without sending location updates to server?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am using kotlin where all registered users are stored in firestore.Is there a way to get all nearby users names when they are logged in without sending location updates of individual users to server?Any suggestion or reference will be very useful as I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get all nearby users names when they are logged in without sending location updates of individual users to server?

No, there is not. Without having the current position of each user, you cannot get nearby users. For Android, there is a library named [GeoFirestore](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android) which can help you achieve this. But note, it's mandatory to have the positions so you can know which user is more closer (or in a range) of your current position.

Comment: yes,i am aware about geofirestore,but i wanted to know if there was anything other than that to get nearby without location.Just out of curiosity,how do game apps show list of  nearby users,do they use geofirestore or something similiar?

Comment: Yes, they use something similar according to the platform on which the game is build.